# Is there a way to update the BLE advertising intervals of a BLE device?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, raspberry-pi3

I got a few Chipolo BLE chips and have started doing some mini IoT projects using the BLE RSSI signal strength to control some IoT home automation depending on where I am relative to a few Raspberry Pi 3's I have around the house. Using the RSSI strength of these BLE chips to tigger location based processes, like play music, turn on lights etc...

The issue I'm running into is that the BLE advertising interval seems to be pretty slow on the Chipolo. Obviously done to preserve energy and make the batter last longer. I know Bluetooth will randomly offsets the advertising signal every nth times to help prevent chip signals overlapping with other devices. Because of this every once in a while there's a burst of frequent RSSI signals but then it drops back down to maybe 1 or two every 3-5 seconds.

Is there a way to update the advertising interval for a BLE chip? Or better yet for a Chipolo chip? With BLE, I was thinking maybe there's a way update the advertising interval if you pair with the chip and write to it's firmware or something. Can this be done? Ideally, the interval would go form say 3000ms to 500ms? I've read that the advertising interval can be as fast as 20ms to as slow as 10.24 seconds.

I'm just starting to be more involved with some hardware projects so I'm still figuring out what exactly is possible and getting used to reading hardware specs (hence the question).

Thanks!